# Find a right angle vertex of quadrangle having: area, 3 functions representing sides and 2 vertices

Tags: geometry

How should I approach finding the coordinates of a vertex of quadrangle in which there is information about:

- 3 linear functions whole lines belong to 3 sides of quadrangle
- area of quadrangle
- 2 other vertices' coordinates
- the angle of unknown vertex is a right angle

[problem - green values are known, looking for C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2bvB.png)

The values in question are:

```
f1(x) = 1.1955x - 440.570
f2(x) = 0.711371x + 891.416
f3(x) = 1.15737x - 485.674
Area = 3000
A = (693.29, 398.23)
B = (736.91, 367.20)
```

For curious, I need this to separate exactly 3000sqm of my land shaped like the figure in the picture.

Comment: You could use vectors. You already have the vectors $C-A$. $A-B$, and $B-D$ (where $D$ is the last vertex), so you can figure out $C-D$ just by adding them. With $C-A$ and $C-D$, you can easily calculate the angle via the dot product. It's quite an analytical solution, but I wouldn't expect anything easier.

Answer (score 0):

First find the intersection of $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ and call it $A$

Then find the intersection of $f_2(x)$ and $f_3(x)$ and call it $B$

Find the distance $AB$

Divide the area by the distance $AB$ and call it $h$
Find a point on the line $f_1(x)$ whose distance from $A$ is $h$

That is the point that you are looking for.